# ProgressBar gets dismissed while loading data from FirebaseStorage

Tags: android

I am trying to get a list of images from a folder that I created in my `FirebaseStorage` bucket. There are total of 20 images and while the app gets all the images, I want to show a `ProgressBar`. Problem is I don't even see the `progressbar` before it gets dismissed. I believe this is something related to `asynchronous` calls that `FirebaseStorage` uses and I tried to solve it by using `AsyncTask` but no luck.

```
private void getBigFlagsFromFirebase() {
    bigFlagsList = new ArrayList<>();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (Utils.isInternetConnectionAvailable(this)) {
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://big-quiz-adrien.appspot.com/");
        StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference().child("level1_data/big_flags");
        storageReference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final ListResult listResult) {
                final AtomicInteger filesCount = new AtomicInteger(listResult.getItems().size());
                for (final StorageReference file : listResult.getItems()) {
                    file.getDownloadUrl()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    bigFlagsList.add(uri);
                                    if (filesCount.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Size: " + bigFlagsList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this gives me 20
                                    }
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            if (filesCount.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Something went wrong. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Something went wrong. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your internet connection and try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Size: " + bigFlagsList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this gives me 0
}
```

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f7f7f7"
    tools:context=".QuestionsActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ads">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/themeName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/less_border_radius"
                android:backgroundTint="#00B050"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="@string/level_1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/flagQuestionsList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                tools:listitem="@layout/country_questions_item" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Ads Banner"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code seems to be doing the following:

- Showing the progress bar.
- Adding a success and failure listener for loading your data.
- Dismissing the progress bar.

Loading the data is asynchronous, so until the loading succeeds or fails, you want the progress bar to stay displayed, but you're immediately dismissing it after registering the listener. So `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)` should be inside the `onSuccessListener` and `onFailureListener` instead.

[Edit]

The reason your progress bar is dismissed after the first image is loaded is because you aren't waiting for all the images to load. For each result, you're registering a listener, but you dismiss the progress bar right afterwards. You should wait for all the `file.getDownloadUri()` calls to complete (either by succeeding or failing).

```
// I'm not sure if these listeners run concurrently and on which threads, so to be safe I'm using an AtomicInteger, feel free to change it to an int if it's thread safe.
final AtomicInteger filesCount = new AtomicInteger(listResult.getItems().size());
for (StorageReference file : listResult.getItems()) {
    file.getDownloadUrl()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                // Do something with the Uri
                if (filesCount.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (filesCount.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i tried that too but in this case, progress dialog disappears after the first image is loaded. I have edited my code, please check.

Comment: @sallu-tech Updated my answer.

Comment: works like a charm. Solved my another problem of taking too much time to load all 20 images. Can you please tell me why is this approach taking very less time to load all images?

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. But it shouldn't have made things faster (or slower, for that matter). Maybe it's faster because you're downloading the same content and there's some caching mechanism involved, can't say for sure though.

Comment: I guess I am using Glide. That's why.

Comment: okay so I found a problem after I made the edits you mentioned. Actually when the progressbar is gone inside if statement of onSuccess, I am storing all the files in ArrayList<Uri> and if I check the size of this list inside this if statement, it gives me 20 which is fine but if I try to access the same list out of this if statement of anywhere in the class, it returns me nothing. I have updated my code snippet. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

remove `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` line from bottom of funcion, and place when you got success/fail callback:

```
  private void getFilesFromFirebase() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://big-quiz-adrien.appspot.com/");
        StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference().child("level1_data/small_flags");
        storageReference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final ListResult listResult) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                for (StorageReference file : listResult.getItems()) {
                    file.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            smallFlagsList.add(uri);
                            Toast.makeText(QuestionsActivity.this, "Size: " + smallFlagsList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        }
                    });

                }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        }
```

and also you should maintain the sequence of view based on which view will render on top and which are behind.

Last view will be on top of all view, if no view contain elevation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that with FrameLayout as it help you have the progressbar behind the recyclerview so once your image got loaded, the recyclerview will hide

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />


          <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/flagQuestionsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            tools:listitem="@layout/country_questions_item" />

    </FrameLayout>
```